# iOS mobile app does not make sufficient closure checks

Tags: bug, closed-questions, ios-app

If the question is open on the iOS app and it is closed you can post an answer to it for a long time (over 30 minutes) after.

[image]

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80846

Comment: You could insta-close your question after voting by click the "Yes, this solved my problem" blue button on top, no need to wait for the other four users. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard not on mobile ;-)

Comment: Huh, true. Well, you can view it in browser, full web theme... :)